# Grails databinding - How to exclude child property

Tags: grails, groovy, data-binding

How can I exclude the child domain property when I use the `grailsWebDataBinder`?

For example, I have domains:

```
class Car {
   String carPropertyToExclude

   Set<Detail> details

   static hasMany = [details: Detail]
}

class Detail {
   String detailPropertyToExclude

   static belongsTo= [car: Car]
}
```

I want to exclude the `detailPropertyToExclude` from Detail  when I call the `bind` method of `grailsWebDataBinder` and give the `car` instance as a parameter

Code:

```
List blackList = ["carPropertyToExclude"]
grailsWebDataBinder.bind(car, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(params), null, blackList)
```

Note:
Don't suggest the `bindable: false` or variants when excluded from anywhere. Only need to know is there a way to do it by providing `blackList` as `bind()` method parameter.

These variants also not working:

```
List blackList = ["carPropertyToExclude", "details.detailPropertyToExclude"]
List blackList = ["carPropertyToExclude", [Detail.class : "detailPropertyToExclude"]]
```

The main question is how to prepare the `blackList` to exclude also child's property?

Answer (score 3):

blacklist parameter supports only direct object properties

you can use DataBindingListener

```
import grails.databinding.events.DataBindingListenerAdapter

class BlackListener extends DataBindingListenerAdapter{
    List<String> list
    //returns false if you want to exclude property from binding
    public Boolean beforeBinding(Object obj, String propertyName, Object value, Object errors) {
        return !list.contains("${obj?.class.name}.${propertyName}".toString())
    }
}

...

List blackList = ["Car.carPropertyToExclude", "Details.detailPropertyToExclude"]
grailsWebDataBinder.bind(car, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(params), 
                new BlackListener(list:blackList) )
```

**UPD:**

Unfortunately the method above does not work with `Collection` binding.

The problem that [SimpleDataBinder.setPropertyValue(...)](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/SimpleDataBinder.groovy#L642) method loses `listener` when processing a list.

Not sure if following workaround is good (potentially context initialization required)

but it's possible to register converter for each black list:

```
import grails.databinding.SimpleDataBinder
import grails.databinding.SimpleMapDataBindingSource
import grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter

SimpleDataBinder setBlackList(SimpleDataBinder binder, Map<Class,List<String>> blackLists) {
    blackLists.each { Class clazz, List<String> blackList ->
        def vc = new ValueConverter(){
            boolean canConvert(Object value){
                return value instanceof Map
            }
            Object convert(Object value){
                def obj = clazz.newInstance()
                binder.bind( obj, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(value), [], blackList )
                return obj
            }
            Class<?> getTargetType(){ clazz }
        }
        binder.registerConverter(vc)
    }
    return binder
}

...

Map blackLists = [
    (Car.class)    : ["carPropertyToExclude"],
    (Detail.class) : ["detailPropertyToExclude"]
]

setBlackList(grailsWebDataBinder,blackLists)

...

grailsWebDataBinder.bind(car, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(params), null, 
         blackLists[car.getClass()] )
```

PS: as alternative possible to set `grailsWebDataBinder.conversionService`...

Comment: Thanks  for reply but it seems not working for same reason as blacklist when the doBind method of webDatabinder called for Details the given listener not provided. So when `obj` is `Details` the listener won't trigger.

Comment: it works for me. check that you adding full class name. also try SimpleDataBinder.

Comment: Which version grails do you use? I use 3.2.11

Comment: i missed that you have `Set<Detail>`. Seems there is a problem for this case. `grailsWebDataBinder` extends `SimpleDataBinder` and they are loosing listener when processing `List/Set`... The issue [present even  latest grails version](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/SimpleDataBinder.groovy#L642). ... i'll try converter or conversion service...

Comment: Thanks for trying, also I have done workaround You can see my answer, but it will be cool to have a data binder for which doesn't matter `Set` or `List`. In my workaround, I have done it by setting the listener as default and made prototype binder the binder didn't lose the default listener.

Answer (score 2):

In a controller you can exclude props from binding by:

```
def someAction(){
  Car car = new Car()
  bindData car, params, [exclude: ['carPropertyToExclude', 'details']]

  car.details = params.list('details').collect{
    bindData new Detail(), [exclude: ['detailPropertyToExclude']]
  }
}
```

You might also want to use the command-objects to represent your form-data.

Comment: It's not what I expect I want to exclude the Detail's field the detailPropertyToExclude

Comment: In my question I have asked only way to do it by black list. I am not interested to do  something manually. This kind of solution almost done. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution based on daggett answer. Maybe in greater versions, the bug is fixed or will be fixed. The bug is that when we give the `listener` as a parameter of `bind` method for child domains the listener isn't triggered but when we set it as class level listener works. Grails version 3.2.11.

I have created the BlackListener like this:

```
public class BlackListListener extends DataBindingListenerAdapter {
private final Map<Class<?>, Collection<String>> blackList;

public BlackListListener(Map<Class<?>, Collection<String>> blackList) {
    this.blackList = blackList;
}

public Boolean beforeBinding(Object obj, String propertyName, Object value, Object errors) {

        Boolean result = Boolean.TRUE;

        Collection<String> list = blackList.get(obj.getClass());

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)) {
            result = !list.contains(propertyName);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I make my own grailsWebDatabinder bean as prototype:

```
<bean id="webDataBinder" class="grails.web.databinding.GrailsWebDataBinder" c:_0-ref="grailsApplication"
      scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="carBinder" class="CarDataBinder" c:_0-ref="webDataBinder"/>
```

and then when I want to use data binder I inject the `webDataBinder` and init listener:

```
public CarDataBinder(GrailsWebDataBinder grailsWebDataBinder) {
    this.grailsWebDataBinder = grailsWebDataBinder;

    DataBindingListener blackListListener = new BlackListListener(
        ImmutableMap.of(
                    Car.class, ImmutableSet.of("carPropertyToExclude"),
                    Detail.class, ImmutableSet.of("detailPropertyToExclude")
            )
        );

    grailsWebDataBinder.setDataBindingListeners(blackListListener);
}
```

and then:

```
void bindData(Car car, Map<?, ?> params) {
    grailsWebDataBinder.bind(car, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(params));
}
```

If there are better ways you can post.